# Faking android version for a specific app

Tags: android, version

I recently upgraded my Android phone to have Android 8.1 (LineageOS 15.1) only to realize that my office mail client does not work with it. When I consulted with the concerned team in the office, the only options I was given is to either wait till the issue is resolved (which will be late this year) or roll back to previous Android version. Now, I don't want to roll back my Phone to the previous version.

Now I am not sure if it's possible/feasible, but I was wondering if there is any way to simulate Android version for a specific app. There are application which can make your device to appear as a completely different device (I tried Market Helper), but couldn't find any option to simulate prior version.

If Android API is backward compatible, shouldn't it be possible to simulate version to specific apps? (I understand that this may not work completely, but it should be worth a shot).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about specific app, but you can edit your device build.prop and change OS version to one, you want.

> Еdit Android Version by locating ro.build.version.release= and changing the current Build Version.